# How to choose a specific 'div' when they share the same class and find a certain element inside it with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access two separate values with beautiful soup. There are multiple 'divs' with the same class and no ID but I'm trying to access this specific one. I've tried finding it with no progress, I've looked on this site as well but still haven't been able to find any answers. How do I do this?

So far, this code:

```
name = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'d-flex justify-content-between mx-3'})
print(name)
```

I get this:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between mx-3">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
<h1 class="item_name mb-0 mr-2">Gucci Bloom Perfume</h1>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap"><a class="mr-2 my-auto" href="https://www.roblox.com/catalog/6803407328" rel="noopener" target="_blank">
<div class="item_roblox_page_link_icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" preserveaspectratio="xMidYMid meet" style="vertical-align: -1.0em;-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:
rotate(360deg);" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g fill="none"><path d="M13.544 10.456a4.368 4.368 0 0 0-6.176 0l-3.089 3.088a4.367 4.367 0 1 0 6.177 6.177L12
18.177" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path><path d="M10.456 13.544a4.368 4.368 0 0 0 6.176 0l3.089-3.088a4.367 4.367 0 1 0-6.177-6.177L12 5.823" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap=
    "round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path></g></svg></div></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But i just want the text in this:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
<h1 class="item_name mb-0 mr-2">Gucci Bloom Perfume</h1>
```

[image]

How would I differ between these? The text values change so trying to find via text is not an option.
[image]

Edit: Here is the [url](https://www.rolimons.com/item/1230403652)

Comment: `name.find('h1')`?

Comment: If you want the text of ```h1``` then just select it - ```soup.find('h1', class_='item_name').text```

Comment: But the texts all share the same class. So do the divs.

Comment: Not in your sample code, so if you want a more concrete answer you should share the url you're trying to scrape.

Comment: I edited the question to have the URL. Just to save time, here it is: https://www.rolimons.com/item/1230403652